# RxJava3 RxImmediateSchedulerRule ExecutorScheduler fair parameter

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java3

RxJava rule for testing with schedulers was

```
import io.reactivex.Scheduler
import io.reactivex.android.plugins.RxAndroidPlugins
import io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler
import io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins
import org.junit.rules.TestRule
import org.junit.runner.Description
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement
import java.util.concurrent.Executor

class RxImmediateSchedulerRule : TestRule {

    private val immediate = object : Scheduler() {

        override fun createWorker(): Worker {
            return ExecutorScheduler.ExecutorWorker(Executor { it.run() }, true)
        }
    }

//    private val immediate = Schedulers.trampoline()

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitNewThreadSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitSingleSchedulerHandler { immediate }
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { immediate }

                try {
                    base.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now with RxJava3

```
ExecutorScheduler.ExecutorWorker(Executor { it.run() }, true, true)
```

Second parameter here is called `fair` but there is no JavaDoc or explanation for this parameter in `ExecutorScheduler` class. Wha is fair paramater used for, and when it should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no JavaDoc or explanation for this parameter in ExecutorScheduler class

That's because `ExecutorScheduler` is an internal class an is not meant to be or expected to be used directly.

The fairness is explained in the JavaDocs of [`Schedulers.from()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/schedulers/Schedulers.html#from-java.util.concurrent.Executor-boolean-boolean-).

Comment: I read the explanation, but i don't get in which situations fair should be false. FIFO and non-overlapping manner isn't what is required for the tests?

Comment: In your case, probably it doesn't matter.